# Assign user to nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes

I have in my application the products, which accepts comments, I want users to be able to make actions on products (create, update ..) and each action should have a comment.

The comments are therefore a nested attribute of product.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, reject_if: proc { |comment| comment['text'].blank? }
```

My problem is that I would like the comments to know which user created them, so I have added a before_validation hook in the model to assign the current user to the comment:

```
  before_validation :assign_current_user
  ...
  private
  def assign_current_user
    user = Thread.current[:current_user]
  end
```

This doesn't work though, because `Thread.current[:current_user]` returns `nil`.

I know that in the model I shouldn't refer to the `current_user`, though I don't know how to pass the current user to the nested_attribute, because I don't want the user_id to be among the `attr_accessible` elements (I don't want users to tweak with whom created the comment).

So I'm not sure what's the right way to do this.

thanks,